# Find similarities in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a list of Customer Names and Supplier Names and since of 2 different countries in the same company.
Unfortunately same Customer and Suppliers have different ids in different countries.
In the other hand the names in the most of the cases are the same or at least very similar.

The goal is to have a PBI report with unified customers/suppliers for both countries.

So I will try to match them by name.

But I want in someway to check for possible same names which have a very small difference like a letter for example i found the Greek name "HARALAMPOS" in the one Country and "CHARALAMPOS" in the other.

I am pretty sure that I can do this in python but I have no idea how. What I want is to extract a list with the Names of the countries (actually it is not only 2 are 8). and find the most similar cases like the example I gave above.

Can anyone navigate me of which libraries I need to use  and which packages from each library  in order to  achieve that ?

I have these 3 columns in different schemas in SQL tables and if you noticed there are some differences for example in Germany the L.T.D. contains dots or for the Customer Name "Hermanos" in Germany is "LOS HERMANOS". This is because of the users that they added the data but is the only possible way to match them for me.

GREECE DATA

[image]

GERMANY DATA:

[image]

US DATA:

[image]

Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Can you give a small reproducible example and the exact matching output ? `print(df.to_dict("list"))`

Comment: @abokey Hi thanks for your answer. Please check the updated post i added some dummy data jus to giving you a better understanding of my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @scr Hi thanks for your answer, Please check the updated post, i added some dummy data that represent the problem in order to give you a better understanding. I have no code so far since I don't know which libraries of python to use for my purpose.

Comment: Search for "Levenshtein Distance" algorithm, there are multiple implementations (in python as well). I'd also take a look at implementing this at a database level, since you mention your data is in SQL tables: if you implement a table/view with the similarity column, you might be better off in processing the data. There are ready functions for various RDBMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`rapidfuzz`](https://pypi.org/project/rapidfuzz/) and [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge).

To give you the general logic, let's compare for example two dataframes (`df_ger`) with (`df_us`) :

```
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import process
​
out = (
        df_ger
           .assign(message_adapted = (df_ger['CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME']
                                       .map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, df_us['CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME']))).str[0])
           .merge(df_us.add_suffix(" (US)"),
                  left_on="message_adapted", right_on="CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME (US)", how="left", indicator="CHECK")
           .rename(columns= {"CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME": "CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME (GE)"})
           .drop(columns="message_adapted")
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME (GE) CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME (US) CHECK
0         LEUTERIS MAVROPOULOS        LEFTERIS MAVROPOULOS  both
1          HARALAMPOS GEORGIOU        CHARALAMPOS GEORGIOU  both
2      ATHLETIC COMPANY L.T.D.       ATHLETIC COMAPANY LTD  both
3                      LTK LTD                  LTK L.T.D.  both
4                GEORGE ANDREW        GEORGE ANDREW GEORGE  both
5                  BLACK POWER                 BLACK POWER  both
6                 LOS HERMANOS                    HERMANOS  both
7               HILLS BROTHERS              HILLS BROTHERS  both
8                   AFOI KLIRU                 AFOI KLIROU  both
9                BOOKER HALIFA               BOOKER HALIFA  both
10              MARCOS COMPANY             MARCO'S COMPANY  both
```

##### # Edit :

Assuming, you have a single dataframe `df` holding two columns and you want to calculate the score of similarity between those, you can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) :

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher​
​
df['SIMILARITY'] = (
                    df.apply(lambda x: str(round(SequenceMatcher(None,
                                                                 x[0].lower(),
                                                                 x[1].lower()).ratio(),2)*100) + "%",
                             axis=1)
                    )
print(df)
​
   CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME (GE) CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME (US) SIMILARITY
0         LEUTERIS MAVROPOULOS        LEFTERIS MAVROPOULOS      95.0%
1          HARALAMPOS GEORGIOU        CHARALAMPOS GEORGIOU      97.0%
2      ATHLETIC COMPANY L.T.D.       ATHLETIC COMAPANY LTD      91.0%
3                      LTK LTD                  LTK L.T.D.      82.0%
4                GEORGE ANDREW        GEORGE ANDREW GEORGE      79.0%
5                  BLACK POWER                 BLACK POWER     100.0%
6                 LOS HERMANOS                    HERMANOS      80.0%
7               HILLS BROTHERS              HILLS BROTHERS     100.0%
8                   AFOI KLIRU                 AFOI KLIROU      95.0%
9                BOOKER HALIFA               BOOKER HALIFA     100.0%
10              MARCOS COMPANY             MARCO'S COMPANY      97.0%
```

Comment: I receive the following error `TypeError: sentence must be a String`. Ans what if i compare more than one columns ? The one column has more rows from the other but i filled the empty rows with a string. So now the two columns have the same rows and the one that had less rows has a specific string instead of empty rows.
`

Comment: To fix it, cast your column as a string, for e.g `df_ger['CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME'] = df_ger['CUSTOMER_SUPPLIER_NAME'].astype(str).fillna("")`. And regarding your second question, as said yesterday, you need to share a reproducible sample of your data `print(df.sample(10).to_dict("list"))` to show how look like your dataframe(s) and also you need to show your exacted expected output.

Comment: For the expected result look the updated post. I know that exist a function like ratio or distance but can I compare two lists ? Also to compare many columns i don't know if it's possible because each column has differences between each other so one result for all will not be accurate.

Comment: Actually i want exactly to the result that i have to add a column with ratio.

Comment: Check out the edit I added to the answer ;)

Comment: and what if I want to take a list with the 4 most similar strings which exist in the other column let's say ?